# asp.net C# verify gridview record is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the below code, but how do I first verify if a record(no multiple records)is indeed selected from the gridview1 before executing the code?

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vSelectedRow = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
    vWORKORDER_TYPE = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    //vTYPE = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    vWORKORDER_BASE_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
    vWORKORDER_LOT_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
    vWORKORDER_SPLIT_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
    vWORKORDER_SUB_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
    vOPERATION_SEQ_NO = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text);
    vRESOURCE_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;
    vHOURLY_COST = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text);
    vUNIT_COST = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text);
    vBURDEN_PER_HR = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[11].Text);
    vBURDEN_PER_UNIT = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[12].Text);
    vBURDEN_PERCENT = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[13].Text);
    vBUR_PER_OPERATION = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[14].Text);
 }
```

Comment: do a simple google search on the following `foreach(DataGridViewRow ....` or if you only need 1 row selected only then change the DataGridView MultiSelect property to false..

Comment: Perhaps, I was not clear with my question. I simply want to know if the user has selected a row from the records shown in the GridView1 control and if the record was selected I can proceed to next action. thanks.

Comment: exactly and you can do it several ways but I think a foreach would do the trick so good luck and like I have mentioned .. do yourself a favor and do a simple google search.. it's not our job to do the research for you now is it...?

Answer (score 0):

You could test for the grid actually having a selected row.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GridView1.SelectedRow == null) return;

    vSelectedRow = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
    vWORKORDER_TYPE = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    //vTYPE = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    vWORKORDER_BASE_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
    vWORKORDER_LOT_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
    vWORKORDER_SPLIT_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
    vWORKORDER_SUB_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
    vOPERATION_SEQ_NO = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text);
    vRESOURCE_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;
    vHOURLY_COST = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text);
    vUNIT_COST = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text);
    vBURDEN_PER_HR = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[11].Text);
    vBURDEN_PER_UNIT = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[12].Text);
    vBURDEN_PERCENT = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[13].Text);
    vBUR_PER_OPERATION = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[14].Text);
```

}

Comment: There is GridView1.SelectedRow , but there is no GridView1.SelectedRows.

Comment: sorry, I missed the asp.net tag. You could still say if (GridView1.SelectedRow == null) return;